# Hat Dash is cut off on mobile

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

When I try to play Hat Dash in portrait mode, half of the canvas is cut off:

[image: A screenshot of the Hat Dash game, but half of the playing area is cut off]

This makes it fairly difficult to react to obstacles in time, especially at higher speeds.

The workaround is easy though, I can just put the phone into landscape, but it would be nice to be able to play in portrait mode.

(If it's relevant, I'm on Chrome on Android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I am aware of this. But not going to have the time to fix it. Workarounds are to put the mobile browser into desktop mode, or (as you said) to put it into landscape mode.

> hat dash on your phone
> unicorn sad in portrait
> see workarounds please